# Android, collections

Tags: java, android

I have a generic list in android.

for other hand i have a listview.

How i could bind the generic list into the listview?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.
Jose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `ArrayAdapter`, if the "generic collection" implements the `List` interface. Otherwise, create your own `Adapter` class, extending `BaseAdapter`.